# How do I know if a TextRange is or contains a Hyperlink?

Tags: c#, wpf, richtextbox

I tried with TextRange.GetPropertyValue(DependencyProperty), but I can't find de Dependency Property that identifies the specific range as hyperlink.

If not with TextRange, is there anyway to find if a selected text inside a RichTextBox is a hyperlink?

Thanks :)

---

Found an answer that is not what I was looking for but still works very well.

[Here](http://www.xtremevbtalk.com/showthread.php?t=303736) is the answer. It's the GetHyperlinkAncestor Method. Hope it helps other people :)

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way is to create a "try catch" and insert this code in the try. `Hyperlink link = new Hyperlink();
                link.NavigateUri = new Uri(link);` If you get an exception it isn't a valid hyperlink. You just have to handle the exception so that the program wan't die.

You can also do it manually by testing the string if it starts with "http://". This is done like this:
`for(int i = 0; i

```
//Do something here
//And to chech the end of the link
if(link[link.lenght-1] == 'm' && link[link.lenght-2] == 'o' && link[link.length-3] == 'c'...
    //Do something
```

}`

I hope you can use this. If not there is stil some possibilites to check the link.